# How i can find all reacheable vertices while honor edge direction

Tags: gremlin

There a official solution (receipt) for find all connected components. But I need same, but where direction of edges taken into account.

So I need to get all nodes where I can go from some node, and vice versa - find all nodes from where I can go to choosen vertex.

My code samples written in Java.

```
// My test graph
    TinkerGraph graph = TinkerGraph.open();
    GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();

        g
            .addV().property(T.id, 1).as("1")
            .addV().property(T.id, 2).as("2")
            .addV().property(T.id, 3).as("3")
            .addV().property(T.id, 4).as("4")
            .addV().property(T.id, 5).as("5")
            .addV().property(T.id, 6).as("6")
            .addE("link").from("1").to("2")
            .addE("link").from("1").to("3")
            .addE("link").from("1").to("4")
            .addE("link").from("2").to("3")
            .addE("link").from("3").to("4")
            .addE("link").from("4").to("5")
            .addE("link").from("4").to("6")
            .addE("link").from("5").to("2")
            .iterate();
```

For example

```
for vertex 1 I expect the result [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for vertices 2, 3, 4, 5 I expect [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for vertex 6 I expect [6]
```

vice versa task:

```
for vertex 6 result [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for vertex 1 result [1]
```

Is it possible? It seems like a common task, but i can't find a questions about it. People just want to find connected components.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single start vertex it's as simple as this:

```
g.V(startId).
  emit().
    repeat(out("link").dedup()).
  dedup()
```

Now, for all vertices at once (or a set of vertices) you would do:

```
g.V().project("vertex","result").
        by().
        by(emit().
             repeat(out("link").dedup()).
           dedup().fold())
```

**Queries on your sample graph**

```
gremlin> (1..6).collect { i ->
           result = g.V(i).emit().repeat(out("link").dedup()).dedup().id().toList()
           "for vertex ${i} result ${result}"
         }
==>for vertex 1 result [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
==>for vertex 2 result [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
==>for vertex 3 result [3, 4, 5, 6, 2]
==>for vertex 4 result [4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
==>for vertex 5 result [5, 2, 3, 4, 6]
==>for vertex 6 result [6]

gremlin> g.V().project("vertex","result").
                 by(id).
                 by(emit().
                      repeat(out("link").dedup()).
                    dedup().id().fold())
==>[vertex:1,result:[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
==>[vertex:2,result:[2,3,4,5,6]]
==>[vertex:3,result:[3,4,5,6,2]]
==>[vertex:4,result:[4,5,6,2,3]]
==>[vertex:5,result:[5,2,3,4,6]]
==>[vertex:6,result:[6]]
```